# Check if it's an external flash drive or usb flash stick?

Tags: linux, usb-drive, external-hdd, flash-memory

When  a usb flash stick or usb external drive get connected, is there any way to check whether it's a usb stick or external flash drive by means of Linux? Is there any utility or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can find information about a hardware device in `/sys`. For a disk drive, look under `/sys/block`. For example, information about `/dev/sdb` is under `/sys/block/sdb`. The file `/sys/block/sdb` contains `1` if the device is removable and `0` otherwise. There's more information in the directory linked to by `device`, including the `model` and `vendor`.

Comment: they're both  removable: external hdd and usb flash stick, how to distinguish  them?

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool `lshw` that is useful for checking out hardware.  You need root privileges to make full use of it.  To find out about your disks, invoke it in the following way:

```
sudo lshw -class disk
```

This will display information about all the disks on your system in a tree-like listing.  If a disk is removable, you will find a line mentioning *removable* as part of its capabilities.  For example, the line may look like this `capabilities: removable`

If you work in a real terminal that doesn't have a scrollbar, add  `| more` to be able to view all output.

Answer (score 0):

For me, `/sys/block/sdb/removable` contains zero, even though the disk is plugged in by USB cable. So I needed an improved answer, and came up with this:

```bash
for dev in $(lsblk -ndo name)
do
    udevadm info --query=property --path=/sys/block/$dev | 
        sed -n "s|^DEVPATH=|$dev/|p" |
        cut -d/ -f1,6 | tr / :
done
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).